# Shannon's Entropy interesting problem I found

Tags: probability, entropy, decision-theory

Here is the problem:

> A student is worried that the metro system might not operate properly
>   when he goes home on a given day. There are two reasons for his
>   worries: it is really `Cold` outside, and they may be working on the
>   construction of metro `Extension`. He estimates that the risk of
>   failure due to the cold weather is `20%`. Independently, they may shut
>   down traffic due to the metro Extension plans with a probability of
>   `50%`.
>
> *How unpredictable is it that the student may not be able to take the
>   subway home, i.e. that the trains are cancelled, either because of the
>   cold weather or due to the construction work (or both)? Answer in
>   terms of entropy, measured in bits.*

The answer:

$$
P(W \lor C) = 1 − P(\neg W)P(\neg C) = 1 − 0.40 = 0.60 \\
ent = −0.6 \log_2(0.6) − 0.4 \log_2(0.4) \approx 0.971
$$

I can understand lets say that 0.6 where it came from and why, but that 0.4 I cannot really what it represents for the student at all.

My approach (which is wrong apparently) is: $ ent = −0.2 \log_2(0.2) − 0.5 \log_2(0.5) −0.1 \log_2(0.1) ≈ 1.28 $, where 0.1 is $0.5 \times 0.2 $ since events are independent.` To my understanding, my expression reads: probability it's cold, or probability there are contractions, or both. What does the correct answer expression read in layman terms?

Comment: You might want to add the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [definition of entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition) is

$$-\sum_{i = 1}^n\left[P(x_i) log(P(x_i))\right]$$

where $x_1, ..., x_n$ are mutually-exclusive events (or symbols, in other interpretations).

In this case, there are two mutually exclusive outcomes: success with probability $P(x_{\mbox{success}}) = 0.4$, and failure with probability $P(x_{\mbox{success}}) = 0.6 = 1 - 0.4$.

Your three-term formula might make sense if there were three mutually-exclusive outcomes: success, failure due to cold but no extension, failure due to extension but not cold, and failure due to both cold and extension. There are a number of problems here:

1. Fundamentally, there is no reason to think that the knowledge of success/failure contains the same amount of information as the knowledge of  both success/failure *and* the exact cause for failure. The entropy of success/failure + reason for failure is greater (in this case) than the entropy of just success/failure.
2. As you can see, for the events to be mutually exclusive, you'd need 4, not 3, events.
3. Your formula has a problem in the "probabilities" not summing to 1. This is just not a valid distribution.